# writing to specific column of a file

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a file that contains one column of integers. I also have a new array of integers. I want to append all the elements of the new array to the next column of my file.

```
myfile

1
2
3 
4
5
6    
7
8
9
10
.
.
.
300

my_array = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,89,90,70...55]

expected results 

1   10
2   20
3   30
4   40
5   50
6   60
7   70
8   89
9   90
10  70
.    .
.    . 
.    .
300  55
```

Comment: You can't literally "append" to the existing file, since the two sets of data are interleaved.  You need to read the existing file and then write a new set of contents to the file containing both the old data and your new data.

Comment: Check out this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66021231/insert-two-values-in-one-line-of-csv-in-python/66021683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your case you can do the below thing

```
old_list = []

with open('myfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
     for i in range(300):
         old_list.append( f.readline().replace('\n', '')  )

old_list = [ '1', '2', '3', .... ]

with open('myfile.txt', 'w+') as f:
     for i in range(300):
         f.write(old_list[i])
         f.write('\t')
         f.write(str(my_array[i]))
         f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Glad! It helped you